# How to compile only modified java files in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to build the project in Eclipse but it cleans the project first and then bulids.
I want to complile files those are modified. how can i achieve the same in Eclipse

Answer (score 5):

Eclipse by default (re)compiles only changed files and those that depend on them, just make sure you have checked `Build automatically` under the `Project` menu so that the compilation happens after saving the file edited.

**EDIT**

Check the settings under

```
Preferences > Java > Compiler
```

and

```
Preferences > Java > Compiler > Building
```

Try to restore the defaults in each one.

Comment: I have checked Build automatically but still it cleans the file.

Comment: @user1363086 how is your project setup? Do you have mutliple projects outputing in the same location? how do you proceed to compile your project? See my edit.